# Spreading data in MySQL database across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Let's say i have long list of names (about 10 000) stored in MySQL database. Is it of any use to divide them into multiple tables eg. by first letter in the name? (table A, table B, etc.)
Would it speed up queries?

Thanks

Comment: databases support *indexes*, which use that exact concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree 10k records isn't a lot at all. Make sure you use indexes for quicker searching. Learn to use [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) when you are writing queries and using indexes.

Also another good idea is to always limit your queries unless you have to list all 10,000 names on one page. For example, have a list and limit the display to 100 names at a time, with pagination.

You would have quicker searches but I can't imagine having to write the code that would go through 26 different tables when searching for something when you don't have the first letter.

Answer (score 3):

10k records is quite small number for a modern RDBMS on a decent hardware. Unless you show more details I would avoid splitting the table — no performance benefits while maintenance and development will be unnecessary complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. 10 000 is not so much. 5 mil. is another story. Use index well and let them together.

Answer (score 0):

no - [partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) the table. data of the same type belongs in one table. you can partition on a number of indexes - I'm going to have a look at partitioning on a sub-string of a column just for my own benefit but its should be possible.